# How to count values in a data range with multiple filters

Tags: excel, excel-formula, date-range, countif

I need to create a module that will count the amount of values in specified date ranges, with other criteria.

For example, I have a list of products (Products A, B , C, D) in column C, and their sale date in column G. 
I need to count all of product A sold before 1/1/1998. I then need to calculate product A sold between 1/1/1998 and 1/1/2005 etc.

I need to be able to run this for all the types of products, and group products together.

E.g. count all of product A & B sold before 1/1/1998.

This has to be done for a new workbook on a weekly basis so ideally needs to be able to be run for a new workbook each week. The tab names always remain the same.

Any help on how to get started would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This answer will assume that your dates are entered as excel dates in column G and not a text.   You can test this by using the formula `=ISNUMBER(G3)` where G3 is one of your dates.  If it returns true, then your date is properly stored for use by excel formulas and this answer.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((($C$1:$C$100="A")+($C$1:$C$100="B"))*($G$1:$G$100<Date(1998,1,1))
```

That is how to hard code it.  Personally I would build a table.  Each row of the table would be a product you are interested in knowing the count for and a sum of the count would give you combined totals.  Repeat the table if you need multiple combinations.

In the following example a single product was counted and then the total for all products listed was the total.  The formula for the example in L3 and copied down for each product was:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$9=$J4)*($G$2:$G$9<K4))
```

The total at the bottom of the table was a simple SUM formula.  Because SUMPRODUCT performs array like operations, avoid using full column references and try to restrict it to the data that needs to be checked.  Otherwise you may notice a slow down in your system as multiple excess calculations are being perfomed.

[image: POC]